# Using Office365 Excel array formulas, how to calculate a weighted average price for each day?

Tags: excel, office365, array-formulas

How to calculate a weighted average price for a selected person, showing their results for each of 5 days. The result needs to be a dynamic array formula that spills into the Results range.  No VBA please, only use and produce array formulas.

Screenshot of the data and desired results:

[image]

One of the formulas I've tried, but pretty much all of them aren't working:

```
=LET(data,A4:D12,dates,index(data,,1),names,INDEX(data,,2),amt,INDEX(data,,3),price,INDEX(data,,4),days,M4#,
    weightedPrice, amt*price,
    resp, MAP(days,LAMBDA(day,SUMIFS(weightedPrice,names,F4,dates,day)/SUMIFS(amt,names,F4,dates,day))),
resp  )
```

Here is a table of the data:

| Day | Name | Amt | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 100 | 10.00 |
| 3 | Joe | 100 | 11.00 |
| 1 | Sandy | 250 | 12.00 |
| 1 | Julie | 400 | 13.00 |
| 2 | Tom | 100 | 14.00 |
| 3 | Sandy | 200 | 15.00 |
| 3 | Sandy | 100 | 16.00 |
| 2 | Tom | 100 | 17.00 |
| 3 | Joe | 100 | 18.00 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A4:D12,
    ξ,M4#,
    φ,F4,
    α,INDEX(ζ,,1),
    β,INDEX(ζ,,2),
    γ,INDEX(ζ,,3),
    δ,INDEX(ζ,,4),
    κ,SUMIFS(γ,β,φ,α,ξ),
    HSTACK(ξ,IF(SEQUENCE(ξ),φ),κ,IFERROR(MMULT(N(ξ=TOROW(α)),γ*δ*(β=φ))/κ,0))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Jos Woolley's answer works great.  Although, to more easily understand it, refactoring is needed.  Below is the same answer but uses descriptive variable names and separates nested components:

```
=LET(data, A4:D12,  days, SEQUENCE(5),  name, F4,  dates, INDEX(data, , 1),  names, INDEX(data, , 2),  amts, INDEX(data, , 3),  prices, INDEX(data, , 4),
    totalAmt,                  SUMIFS(amts, names, name, dates, days),
    weightedPrices,            amts * prices * (names = name),
    daysByDatesMatrixBoolean,  days = TOROW(dates),   // 2D matrix of true & false
    daysByDatesMatrix,         N(daysByDatesMatrixBoolean),   // convert to ones and zeros
    totalWeightedPrices,       MMULT(daysByDatesMatrix, weightedPrices),
    waPrices,                  IFERROR(totalWeightedPrices / totalAmt, 0),
    response,                  HSTACK(days, IF(days, name), totalAmt, waPrices),
 response  )    // To debug replace with another component name, for example daysByDatesMatrixBoolean instead of response
```

Explanation of the formula steps:

1. First, the data is defined and extracted.
2. The total amount is calculated which will be the denominator in the final calculation.
3. Individual amounts are weighted (multiplied) by their price resulting in a one dimensional array.
4. A two dimensional matrix (array) of all dates for each day is created. If the date exists in the data (has an amount) the value is set to true, else false.
5. The matrix is converted to 1's and 0's so it can be used for calculations.
6. The two arrays are multiplied together using the matrix multiplication function MMULT() resulting in a one dimensional array of the weighted prices.
7. The weighted prices are divided by each day's total amount which is the weighted average price.
8. Then using HSTACK(), the result (response) is organized with the required columns and the weighted average price as the last column.

Comment: `INDEX` can return both a *range* and an *array*; `CHOOSECOLS` can only return an *array*. And `SUMIFS` requires a *range* for its *sum_range* and *criteria_range* arguments. `=SUMIFS(C4:C12,INDEX(A4:D12,,2),"Joe")` is perfectly valid, though you can't even get Excel to accept `=SUMIFS(C4:C12,CHOOSECOLS(A4:D12,2),"Joe")`.